# How can I make a complaint against a user who downvoted me in revenge?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

How can I make a complaint against a user who is trying to take revenge on my **one downvote** by downvoting my answers with silly reasons?

This is not a sudden flood of downvotes, it's about only one vote. But it matters!

The comments have been already removed by the user, but I need to know the answer to my question.

Comment: Please see my edit this is not a duplicate..!!@jonrsharpe

Comment: One vote? No, it doesn't matter. If their comments are rude or unconstructed flag them as such, but a single vote is hardly revenge.

Comment: The comments have been removed but it was clearly a revenge i am damn sure..!! @jonrsharpe

Comment: @downvoters please mention the resoan.!!

Comment: Regarding your last comment, the latest attempt to force downvoters to comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325616/3001761

Comment: perhaps you should create another meta post complaining about the downvotes on this one etc etc, you could spend days doing that. Or alternatively you could just move on.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> it's about only one vote. But it matters!

No, it does not.

Individual people are going to disagree with you. Some of these disagreements will never be resolved. These are facts of life that you're going to have to deal with. But you're not going to die just because of one unresolved dispute.

This will not be the last time such a thing will happen to you.

You are upset. And it's OK to be upset. But complaints over petty matters such as this are unlikely to be entertained.

Comment: it's ok to disagree with someone's opinion but the person who is getting disagree should have a proper reason for that sir. But this was a silly reason he was downvoting because i have done that..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya like this reason? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/188189

Comment: Still the question is also downvoted..!! By the way thank you @RobertLongson and BoltClock. I got my answer..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya - Also note that SO has processes in place to prevent "revenge-downvoting". Like BoltClock says, don't worry too much about a couple of DVs every now and then.